# How do I write a cronjob?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cron-task

So I've been looking up cronjobs for the past few minutes... I have a general sense of how to add one to my websites ubuntu system.... I need to make my system run a corn job once a minute (according to the software I'm having it use).

1. First I log in via SSH..
2. Then I enter root mode.
3. Then I type crontab -e
4. Then each line is a scheduled cron job....

The instructions on the softwares site says to just run the following command once a minute:

```
/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 -d max_execution_time=0 /home/mywebsite.com/215a/applications/core/interface/task/task.php 8222157ad26eg58q51dh343ha7j472az
```

I know that the start of the crontab line should read like this:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/command
```

My confusion is this.... Can I just put the instructed command in the /path/to/command part, or do I need to create a file and put the files address there? Also if I have to make a file, what format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it like so

In the `crontab`

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 -d max_execution_time=0 /home/mywebsite.com/215a/applications/core/interface/task/task.php 8222157ad26eg58q51dh343ha7j472az
```

==========================================================

Alternatively, you may put the command in a **shell script** and execute the shell script.

command.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 -d max_execution_time=0 /home/mywebsite.com/215a/applications/core/interface/task/task.php 8222157ad26eg58q51dh343ha7j472az
```

Make sure to make the shell script file executable

```
$chmod a+x command.sh
```

Then in the **crontab**

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/command.sh
```

============OR=============

Without making the shell script file executable

In the **crontab**

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/command.sh
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been away. Yes thank you! perfect help! @linuxartisan